# Create Function App using Terraform with functions extension version 4

Tags: azure, azure-devops, terraform, azure-functions, terraform-provider-azure

I have little problem that I am trying to solve.

I am trying to create function apps using terraform as IaC and my only problem is with functions extension version in version 4.

When I insert the variable like this:

```
functions_extension_version = "~4"
```

I get this version as custom (I am trying to create Dotnet version 6 so it must be version 4)

[image: Function App Version]

But when I use version 3 like this:

```
functions_extension_version = "~3"
```

it works fine

[image: Function Version]

I know my app service plan is support functions extension version 4 becuase when I try to create manually it is working as expected.

Thanks

edit:

full TF code:

```
resource "azurerm_windows_function_app" "function_windows" {
  # condition
  count = var.to_create ? 1 : 0

  # basic info configuration
  name                       = var.name
  resource_group_name        = var.resource_group_name
  location                   = var.location
  storage_account_name       = data.azurerm_storage_account.storage_account.name
  storage_account_access_key = data.azurerm_storage_account.storage_account.primary_access_key
  service_plan_id            = var.app_service_plan_id

  # function configuration
  https_only                  = true
  functions_extension_version = "~4"

  site_config {
    application_stack {
      dotnet_version = var.runtime == "dotnet" ? var.runtime_version : null
      java_version   = var.runtime == "java" ? var.runtime_version : null
      node_version   = var.runtime == "node" ? var.runtime_version : null
    }

    scm_use_main_ip_restriction = true
    elastic_instance_minimum    = local.elastic_instance_minimum
  }

  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }
  tags = var.tags
}
```

Comment: Can you provide function app terraform code to check where exactly it is blocking you?

Comment: Of course I will edit the theard

Comment: Someone is familiar with the issue?

Answer (score 0):

> Your app is pinned to an unsupported runtime version for ‘dotnet’. For better performance, we recommend using one of our supported versions instead: ~3.

*There are no issues with your terraform code, but the issue I found is with the **version running in the backend**.*

According to [@Sandro Pereira](https://blog.sandro-pereira.com/2022/07/28/azure-function-app-issues-your-app-is-pinned-to-an-unsupported-runtime-version-for-dotnet-for-better-performance-we-recommend-using-one-of-our-supported-versions-instead-3/)'s blog,

If you encounter this kind of error or a similar alert, it signifies that the runtime version you defined uses an unsupported version of .NET Framework. In some instances, although your
`function runtime version = ~4` works with .NET framework v6.0, but it actually runs using v4.0 in the backend.

> Runtime version ~3 normally runs on top of .NET Framework v4.0. However, **runtime version ~4 requires .NET Framework v6.0**.

By referring [terraform registry](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/function_app), I created the replica of a function app with terraform and deployed successfully.

*Code snippet:*

```
resource "azurerm_function_app" "newfunc" {
  name                       = "test-azure-functions"
  location                   = azurerm_resource_group.newfunc.location
  resource_group_name        = azurerm_resource_group.newfunc.name
  app_service_plan_id        = azurerm_app_service_plan.newfunc.id
  storage_account_name       = "mystorage"
}
```

[image]

*After successful deployment in Azure portal*:

[image]

***You can validate which version of .NET is running for your function app by checking:***

[Resource Explorer (azure.com)](https://resources.azure.com/)

Validate the *netFrameworkVersion*:

[image]

*Note: Refer the above blog for path to validation*

Comment: I have checked and they have issue with the new function app module, but the old one is working, thanks